# Smalltalk - Inserting a TAB character (Visual Works)

Tags: string, smalltalk, squeak

I'm having some trouble inserting a tab between two strings.

```
stringOne := 'Name'.
stringTwo := 'Address'.
```

I've tried:

```
info := stringOne, String tab, stringTwo.
```

or

```
info := stringOne, Character tab asString, stringTwo.
```

But none of those two messages are understood.  I'm using Visual Works.

Answer (score 3):

Goog gave you a way of making a String that included a tab

```
String with: Tab
```

and by yourself you discovered that Tab wasn't understood in VisualWorks and should be replaced by

```
Character tab
```

**so put those 2 things together** in a workspace evaluate to check it gives a String containing a tab Character

```
String with: Character tab
```

then use that in your concatenation

```
info := stringOne, (String with: Character tab), stringTwo.
```

(If you're going to do a lot of concatenation then use a `WriteStream` not `,`)

Comment: it is at least dangerous to use the comma operator without precaution. And there's a shortcut for String with:, it's called asString. So I'd rewrite this as stringOne copy , Character tab asString , stringTwo

Comment: Except that in some versions of VisualWorks, the class Character doesn't implement asString. Checked it it in VW 3.5 and 7.8. This is one of the reasons why I almost always use WriteStream.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Visual Works to check, but in IBM Smalltalk `Tab`(note the case) is a tab character.
Maybe try this:

```
info := stringOne, Tab asString, stringTwo.
```

---

edit (re: your comment):

Okay, either `Tab` is not the right name for a tab character, or your character class doesn't respond to `asString`
Try seeing what `Tab class` gives you, if it answers "Character", then you just need to find out how to change a Character into a String in VisualWorks. If it doesn't answer "Character", then we haven't found the right name for tab characters in VisualWorks.

---

edit2:

I don't know the short way to turn a character into a string in Visual Works, so here is a solution that should work anyway. This is all that `asString` would do anyway:
Since you'd probably want to use it multiple times, you can save it as a string,

```
tabString := String with: Tab.
info := stringOne, tabString, stringTwo
```

Comment: #asString, message not understood. It doesn't work on Visual Works. Hmmm I can't even find it online

Comment: It answers to Character. So Character tab is correct, but there is not method to convert it to string. It's ok my stuff will just look a little unaligned.  Thanks though

Comment: Ah okay well, then it's just down to the specifics of VisualWorks, which I don't know about. I have however added a longer solution that should hopefully work...

Answer (score 2):

Its shortest to use macro expansion:

```
info := '<1s><T><2s>' expandMacrosWith: one with: two
```

Answer (score 1):

WriteStream based solution (it's a bit more verbose, but scales nicely and you can use it in loops, like do:separatedBy)

```
ws := (String new:50) writeStream.
ws
    nextPutAll: stringOne;
    tab;
    nextPutAll: stringTwo.
info := ws contents.
```

Or if you really like one liner code:

```
info := (String new writeStream) nextPutAll: stringOne; tab; nextPutAll: stringTwo; contents.
```